# $\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} z_{n}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, analysis

> **Problem:** A complex sequence $z_n \in \mathbb C(|z_n|\leq 1)$, and $\forall d \in \mathbb Z_{+}$,
>   $$
> \lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} z_{n+d} \overline{z_{n}}=0
> $$
>   Prove that
>   $$
> \lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} z_{n}=0
> $$

**Here's a possible method**:

Since $D \in \mathbb Z_{+}$,
$$
\overline{\lim}_\limits {N \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} z_{n}-\frac{1}{D N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{d=1}^{D} z_{n+d}\right)=0
$$
so it is equivalent to prove that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists D \in \mathbb Z_{+}$
$$
\overline{\lim}_\limits{N \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{1}{D N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{d=1}^{D} z_{n+d}\right|<\varepsilon
$$
set $D>1/\varepsilon$, from Cauchy's inequality we have
$$
\overline{\lim}_\limits {N \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{1}{D N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{d=1}^{D} z_{n+d}\right|^{2} \leq \overline{\lim}_\limits{N \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left|\frac{1}{D} \sum_{d=1}^{D} z_{n+d}\right|^{2}\leq \overline{\lim}_\limits {N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{D^{2}} \sum_{c, d=1}^{D} z_{n+c} \overline{z_{n+d}} \leq \frac{1}{D^{2}} \sum_{c, d=1}^{D} \overline{\lim}_\limits {N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} z_{n+c} \overline{z_{n+d}}
$$
thus, when $c\neq d$, from 
$$
\overline{\lim}_\limits {N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} z_{n+c} \overline{z_{n+d}}=0
$$
we deduce
$$
\frac{1}{D^{2}} \sum_{d=1}^{D} \overline{\lim}_\limits{N \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left|z_{n+d}\right|^{2} \leq \frac{1}{D^{2}} \sum_{d=1}^{D} \overline{\lim}_\limits{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} 1=\frac{1}{D }<\varepsilon
$$
so that the proposition is proven.

> **My question is :** Is there any other approaches to this problem?